# Lookup correct, yet no ping

Tags: networking, dns, raspberry-pi, bind

I have setup a local raspberry pi to be a DNS server for the office. It worked (almost) perfectly, until we moved down a floor in the office.

The firewall and setup for the network is exactly the same, however my RaspberryPI DNS host doesn't.

The zones are correct and I can lookup the local domain and get the correct result. However, it doesn't ping.

From my Mac:

```
Pauls-MacBook-Pro:~ paulp$ nslookup mobile.domain.office
Server:     10.0.0.196
Address:    10.0.0.196#53

Name:   mobile.domain.office
Address: 10.0.0.201



Pauls-MacBook-Pro:~ paulp$ ping mobile.domain.office
ping: cannot resolve mobile.domain.office: Unknown host



Pauls-MacBook-Pro:~ paulp$ ping -c 3 10.0.0.201
PING 10.0.0.201 (10.0.0.201): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 10.0.0.201: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=1.318 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.201: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=2.562 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.201: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=26.039 ms

--- 10.0.0.201 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 1.318/9.973/26.039/11.372 ms



Pauls-MacBook-Pro:~ paulp$ dig mobile.domain.office

; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> mobile.domain.office
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 44066
;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;mobile.domain.office.  IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
mobile.domain.office. 7200  IN  A   10.0.0.201

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
domain.office.  7200    IN  NS  raspberrypi.domain.office.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
raspberrypi.domain.office. 7200 IN  A   10.0.0.196

;; Query time: 1 msec
;; SERVER: 10.0.0.196#53(10.0.0.196)
;; WHEN: Wed Apr 27 15:05:42 2016
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 100
```

The address of `mobile.domain.office` is `10.0.0.201`. My mac can reach it perfectly, so can the DNS "server". The DNS server also resolved the DNS as well as my mac, yet I can't reach it. However, the DNS "server" does have a high latency and is slow to respond:

```
root@raspberrypi:/etc/bind# ping -c 3 mobile.domain.office
PING mobile.domain.office (10.0.0.201) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.0.0.201: icmp_req=1 ttl=64 time=977 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.201: icmp_req=2 ttl=64 time=360 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.201: icmp_req=3 ttl=64 time=352 ms

--- mobile.domain.office ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 31348ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 352.624/563.543/977.893/293.006 ms
```

As suggested [here](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-networking-3/bind9-host-does-reslove-a-dns-name-but-ping-says-unknown-host-619628/#post4221353), I also changed `/etc/nsswitch.conf` to have `dns` after `files`, that didn't help either.

From what I can see, the zones are correct too. This is the zone for `domain.zone`:

```
;
; BIND data file for local loopback interface
;
$TTL    7200
@       IN      SOA     domain.office. root.domain.office. (
                              2         ; Serial
                         172800         ; Refresh
                          14400         ; Retry
                        2419200         ; Expire
                         604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL

                        NS      raspberrypi.domain.office.
domain.office   IN  NS      raspberrypi.domain.office.
domain.office   IN  A       10.0.0.201
raspberrypi         IN  A       10.0.0.196
mobile              IN  A       10.0.0.201
```

I have also done a new reload on the name server control utility:

```
root@raspberrypi:/etc/bind# rndc reload domain.office
zone reload up-to-date
```

Also, both my Mac and the raspberry pi have the correct settings.

Ifconfig for my mac:

```
Pauls-MacBook-Pro:~ paulp$ ifconfig
[...]
en0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ether ac:bc:32:95:04:bb
    inet6 fe80::aebc:32ff:fe95:4bb%en0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x4
    inet 10.0.0.185 netmask 0xfffffe00 broadcast 10.0.1.255
    nd6 options=1<PERFORMNUD>
    media: autoselect
    status: active
[...]
```

The raspberry pi:

```
root@raspberrypi:/etc/bind# ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:f4:2b:3c
          inet addr:10.0.0.196  Bcast:10.0.1.255  Mask:255.255.254.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:3208 errors:0 dropped:2 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2353 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:844113 (824.3 KiB)  TX bytes:324170 (316.5 KiB)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: And the Pi is in the same subnet as your MacBook?

Comment: Yes. It seems to. I'll update the question.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out, for me, to be a network issues. We reset the primary DNS in the router once again to the DNS server. Also, did a DNS flush on my mac. Afterwards it all worked.